# MVC, c# .edmx file - Adding a new controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I am adding a new controller that makes use of a number of tables. I have added these tables to the .edmx file. For the add new controller dialog box, it ask for the Model Class. I do see the 3 tables I dropped into the .edmx but not sure which one to choose or if there is a way to choose a model that is a consolidated version of those 3 tables.

Comment: You really need to market an accepted answer to some of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where a view model would come into play. First of all create a view model that contains properties for the 3 models you want to render on your view:

```
public class FakeViewModel
{

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; } 
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, create a new instance of the view model and populate it accordingly. EG:

```
public ActionResult FakeAction(int id)
{
    var product = _repository.Get<Product>(id);
    var company = _repository.Get<Company>();
    var user = _repository.Get<user>();

    var model = new FakeViewModel{
       Product = product,
       Company = company,
       User  = user
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

On your view, you will now have a strongly typed view for the FakeViewModel.

Comment: I tried to add the class into the Models folder. I get the swiggly lines after the word that comes after Public. In your example it would be Public, Company, User I substituted what you have with my own tables.

Comment: Also in my class, is the only thing I need to add something like you have above or is more needed? Keep in mind I substituted the tables you have with my own tables.

Comment: I would recommend, that you take a look at the music store or nerd dinner sample apps and review the mvc getting started tutorials: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ 
http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials